# Visual Studio Code can not load DSC Modules other than PSDesiredStateConfiguration

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code installed and enabled the PowerShell Extension

I would like to write a Desired State Configuration with some custom modules like `xHyper-V` and `xPSDesiredStateConfiguration`.

Now the problem is, that Visual Studio Code only finds the `PSDesiredStateConfiguration` DSC Resource which is a default resource, when I want to Import them via `Import-DSCResource`. Any other installed DSC Resource can not be loaded by Visual Studio Code. in PowerShell ISE everything works as you can see here (left is VSCode, right ISE):

[image: Broken DSC Resource in VSCode]

The weird thing though, is that this only effects the editor itself. in the terminal in vscode it finds DSC Resources in all modules. see this example:

```
PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts\DesiredStateConfiguration> Get-DscResource xVHD

ImplementedAs   Name                      ModuleName                     Version    Properties
-------------   ----                      ----------                     -------    ----------
PowerShell      xVHD                      xHyper-V                       3.17.0.0   {Name, Path, DependsOn, Ensure...}


PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts\DesiredStateConfiguration> Get-DscResource WindowsFeature

ImplementedAs   Name                      ModuleName                     Version    Properties
-------------   ----                      ----------                     -------    ----------
PowerShell      WindowsFeature            PSDesiredStateConfiguration    1.1        {Name, Credential, DependsOn, Ensure...}
```

it also finds the modules themselves:

```
PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts\DesiredStateConfiguration> Get-Module xHyper-V, PSDesiredStateConfiguration -ListAvailable


    Verzeichnis: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.17.0.0   xHyper-V


    Verzeichnis: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.1        PSDesiredStateConfiguration         {Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager...}
```

The only difference is that they are in different `$env:PSModulePath`s but It still does not work when I copy the `xHyper-V` module to the Path where `PSDesiredStateConfiguration` also resides.

What's funny is that this only seems to effect the IntelliSense of the Editor. If I run the Configuration with my Custom DSC modules, it still creates the `*.mof` file correctly.

How can I fix this?

What I have tried to fix the issue:

- deleted and re-installed all custom DSC Modules
- uninstalled PowerShell extension in VSCode, restarted VSCode and installed it again
- completely reinstalled VSCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facepalm. Slightly embarassing, but 1 Minute after I posted this I found the answer:

I also have `PowerShell Core` installed. One Core Session was opened in the Terminal of VSCode in the back, it wasn't the active one, but it somehow still affected Intellisense.

Simply Close the `Core` Terminals and everything will work as expected.

**or**

Check in an elevated `PowerShell Core` if `$env:PSModulePath` contains the folder where the DSC modules are in with `$env:PSModulePath -split ';'`. The folder most likely won't be in there. use the following command to add it, and then after vscode restart and pwsh restart IntelliSense will always work since pwsh will now also look in the correct directory:

```
$CurrentValue = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $CurrentValue + [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator + "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules", "Machine")
```